# I can not configure the route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I created a simple search engine with a controller that has a method that will accept the student parameter

this is my razor page code

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="row form-group text-center">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input placeholder="Город" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.Profession" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input placeholder="Город" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.City" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input placeholder="Курс" class="form-control mdl-textfield__input" asp-for="@Model.Course" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input placeholder="Специализация" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.Specialization" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Поиск" class="btn btn-primary " />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

this is UserModel

```
public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
public string Profession { get; set; }
public string City { get; set; }
public int Course { get; set; }
public string Specialization { get; set; }
```

my controllers GET and POST

```
 [Route("Index")]
 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult Index()

 [Route("Index")]
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Index(UserModel model)
```

after search my rout Search/Index without parametrs. how to create rout like Search/Index/Profession=Coder/City=London/Course=4/Specialization=Code . my route is static and i can`t go to back or copy url. but i catch Document Expired

sorry my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a basic example

```
[RoutePrefix("Search")]               //place this routeprefix since "Search' is common
public class TestController: Controller
{
    [Route("Index")]                 // "Search/Index" route for GET 
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()

    [Route("Index")]                  // "Search/Index" route for POST 
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(UserModel model)
```

Now for `Search/Index/Profession=Coder/City=London/Course=4/Specialization=Code`.
firstly as per my understanding it should be as below.

Please check carefully.

`Search/Index?Profession=Coder&City=London&Course=4&Specialization=Code`.

Explanation about the above route. After `Index` it contains `?` which suggests that querystring follows after `?`. Also `Profession=Coder` is one pair of querystring and is followed with `&` suggesting that there is another querstring which is `City=London`, followed by `&` suggesting that there is another querstring which is `Course=4`, henceforth.

And the route defined is as below

```
    [Route("Index/{Profession=Profession}/{City=City}/{Course=Course}/{Specialization=Specialization}")]  
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Profession(string Profession,string City,int Course,string Specialization)
```

Comment: [RoutePrefix("Search")]  can`t find. how to fix it?

Comment: RoutePrefix is in `System.Web.Mvc` namespace of asp.net mvc5

Comment: There is no need to use double "Index" attribute. If method marked as get or post same named actions will be process the request.

Comment: i use 2.2 version

Comment: asp net core mvc

Comment: ok, then try `[Route("Search")] ` instead `[RoutePrefix("Search")]`